# Cleansing Duplicate Data Python

Tags: python, apache-beam, data-cleaning

trying to remove duplicate data from json file using apache beam, I've tried it but it doesn't work with the code below

with input json file

```
{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}
```

```
def CleansingDuplicateData(element):
  fieldlist ={"idtrx"}
  temp = []
  res = dict()
 
  if element is not None:
    for key, value in element.items():
      if key in fieldlist:
        if value not in temp:
          temp.append(value)
          res[key] = value
  if element is not None:
    if element[key] in res:
      return None
  return(element)
```

can someone help me about this?

Comment: {"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"},
{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"},
{"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}

i need to remove the duplicate data

Comment: Your function either returns `None` or it returns `element`. Did you want to return `res` ?

Comment: because i want to remove the duplicate data, it is wrong? can u give me example?

Comment: Say the input was `{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2023-01-01 11:11:11.0"}, {"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}` What should the output of the function be then?

Comment: expected output is remove teh duplicate data, ```{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2023-01-01 11:11:11.0"}, {"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}``` should be like that

Comment: OK. What's the logic that means the result contains `{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2023-01-01 11:11:11.0"}` and does not contain `{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}`. i.e. how do we decide between items that have the same "idtrx" but different "UserCreatedDate" ?

Comment: what i need just to remove the data with the same idtrx

Comment: So, when two elements have the **same** idtrx but **different** UserCreatedDate, which one should be used for the output?

Comment: when two elements have the same idtrx, i need to remove one of them

Comment: **Which** one should be removed?

Comment: the first one to be kept, the another one removed

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the requirement is for the output to include the first-appearing element for each value of `idtrx`.

This can be achieved by building an intermediate dictionary with values of `idtrx` as its keys, and forming a list from the values of that dictionary as the output:

```
import json

def cleaned(raw_vals, key_field='idtrx'):
    # iterate in reverse so the first item for each key ends up being kept
    vals_by_key = {dct[key_field]: dct for dct in reversed(raw_vals)}
    return list(reversed(vals_by_key.values()))


input_json = '[{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}]'
input_list = json.loads(input_json)
output_list = cleaned(input_list)
output_json = json.dumps(output_list)

print(output_json)
```

Output:

```
[{'idtrx': 'YI-021122', 'UserCreatedDate': '2020-05-12 09:24:25.0'}, {'idtrx': '2F-002335', 'UserCreatedDate': '2016-09-07 00:00:00.0'}]
```

Note that your input needed additional `[ ]` enclosing it, in order to be valid JSON.

Comment: i have already load the json at the beginning with this code 
```
def loadAsJson(element):
  data = json.loads(element) #Load data as json
  return(data)
```

and the expected output is to be back in the data again

Comment: OK, I added a step to convert the output to JSON. If you have already converted your input to a list, then you can just call `cleaned` with that list, and skip my steps that do the loading from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set to keep a note of the values you've observed so far as you iterate over your list of dictionaries.

Something like this:

```
import json

js = """[{"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"YI-021122","UserCreatedDate":"2020-05-12 09:24:25.0"}, {"idtrx":"2F-002335","UserCreatedDate":"2016-09-07 00:00:00.0"}]"""
result = []
observed = set()
for d in json.loads(js):
    if (v := d.get('idtrx')) is not None and v not in observed:
        result.append(d)
        observed.add(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'idtrx': 'YI-021122', 'UserCreatedDate': '2020-05-12 09:24:25.0'}, {'idtrx': '2F-002335', 'UserCreatedDate': '2016-09-07 00:00:00.0'}]
```